# v21 update to Android Studio, now I have activity_main & activity_main (v21)? Where do I work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio was giving me a warning regarding an update to v21, so I did it. Now under my activity_main folder I have 2 files: activity_main and activity_main (v21). If I work on the activity_main folder, will Android studio update both files? Is the (v21) file necessary? I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Hello DrCindie, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is very poor in terms of content; users are a bit “hard” on new people asking “bad questions”. In spite of the above (or what my opinion is about your question), The information you’re looking for is located here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources (notably the “Providing alternative resources” section).

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's overwhelming to learn alone sometimes. @MartinMarconcini

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow encourages these types of questions to be downvoted/flagged/removed, but I will do a little bit better.

When you see sub/similar folders in your `res/` folder (resources), what you’re seeing is/are alternate resources that will be used if the `config_qualifier` matches.

E.g.:

The `layouts` value folder is often seen to have `layouts-v21` or similar versions.

Say you have this XML:

`res/layout/main.xml`

and you need to provide a layout for devices running API 21 or higher that contains a specific widget/view that only works on API 21…

One solution (but not the only one) is to provide an alternate resource for those devices and fallback to the original one, when not found:

`res/layout-v21/main.xml`

Android will *automagically* pick the “correct” one for you at runtime, if the device is running on API 21 or higher.

if you *don’t* provide it (say you only have main in the /layout folder, not the v21), when android fails to find it in layout-v21, it will try to go to the next (by precedence), in this case, just /layout.

If it can’t find it there, you will get an exception. :)

And that's “resources” 101. Hope it helps.

Now… to answer your question. You will need to work on “both” if they are different. In truth, depending which minApi you support (apparently below 21, otherwise you wouldn’t need to make an exception). If that’s the case (you’re supporting older than 21 devices), then yes, you need to work on both to ensure they work on all platforms.

Alternatively, for layouts, it’s usually not needed to have both. I’d say it’s preferred to have a single common layout, and specify `styles.xml` and `themes` in the respective `v21` sub-folders.

What I mean is… if `some_attribute` only works on API 21+, you could have a:

`values/styles.xml` that doesn’t have the some_attribute and a 
`values-v21/styles.xml` that has it. There are multiple ways to work around this and sometimes you do have to “copy paste” things to duplicate them. If you can support api 21+, them you will less often have to make these exceptions. (Since API 21 and 23 brought a load of changes… it’s common to make the distinction right there at that API level, like Android Studio does for you, because API 21 brought a lot of things that are unsupported in lower apis).