# run app shows old XML layout that no longer exists in the project

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a simple android project where I'm populating a list of items in a database. To do this I'm using `RecyclerView` showing in my `activity_main.xml`

These are my two (and only two that exist) xml files

`activity_main.xml`

```
package com.twocrows.foretoldapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.adapter.ChartAdapter;
import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.entity.Chart;
import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.viewmodel.ChartViewModel;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ChartViewModel chartViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ChartAdapter adapter = new ChartAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        chartViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChartViewModel.class);
        chartViewModel.getAllCharts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Chart>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Chart> charts) {
                adapter.setCharts(charts);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which shows in the preview like this
[image]

`chart_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="location"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="248dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="248dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:text="Chart Name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_dateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:text="MM/DD/YYYY"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.twocrows.foretoldapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.adapter.ChartAdapter;
import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.entity.Chart;
import com.twocrows.foretoldapp.viewmodel.ChartViewModel;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ChartViewModel chartViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ChartAdapter adapter = new ChartAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        chartViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChartViewModel.class);
        chartViewModel.getAllCharts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Chart>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Chart> charts) {
                adapter.setCharts(charts);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is that whenever I try to run the app, it's showing me an old version of the main activity xml file. I no longer even have these components in the xml so I don't understand where they are coming from.

#Things I've tried

- Invalidate cache/ restart
- clean build
- edit configuration, uncheck 'skip installation if apk has not changed'

Nothing so far has worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: delete app and reinstall it and rebuildProject

Comment: @chandmohd what do you mean by delete and reinstall the app? It's being run on the virtual android device.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your app showing an old version of the activity_main.xml, even though you no longer have those components in the file, may be due to having two different layout resource files for a single activity.
You can check your layout resource directory to see if you have two different versions of the main activity layout file, such as "main.xml" and "main.xml(v21)", which may be causing the confusion.  [You can see the reason for having multiple files in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338231/9309388)

In this case, the solution would be to make sure that you're editing the correct layout file. If you edited an XML file but your emulator is running the v21 file, you can copy your code and paste it into the other file.

If you've made changes to the correct file but are still seeing the old version in the emulator, you can try cleaning and rebuilding the project, or even deleting the app from the emulator and reinstalling it.

If you continue to experience the issue, you may also want to check the AndroidManifest.xml file to ensure that the correct layout file is being used for the main activity. This file can be found in the "app" directory of your project.